# Understanding px to em to percentages for responsive design

Tags: html, css

So I came across some conversion math **Target ÷ Context = Result Target** to convert px to em percentages.

I understand that this keeps your layout fluid. What i don't understand is what to  plug into the equation. Do i use this on everything i would normally use pixel sizes on ? Can anyone enlighten me on the proper way to convert and design using this ? Thanks

Comment: `px` and `em` are two incommensurable units; any “formula” for conversion is based on a misunderstanding, just like any formula for converting apples to kilograms. No play with units “keeps your layout fluid”. Fluid layout is a broad topic, and at SO, you should ask specific concrete questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find more information about that formula on [A List Apart](http://alistapart.com/article/fluidgrids)

> ```
>   target ÷ context = result
> ```
>
> If we assume the body’s default type size to be 16px, we can plug each
>   desired font-size value into this formula. So to properly match our
>   header to the comp, we divide the target value (24px) by the font-size
>   of its container (16px):
>
> ```
>   24 ÷ 16 = 1.5
> ```
>
> So the header is 1.5 times the default body size, or 1.5em, which we
>   can plug directly into our stylesheet.
>
> ```
>    h1 {
>      font-family: Georgia, serif;
>      font-size: 1.5em;        /* 24px / 16px = 1.5em */
>    }
> ```

When dealing with text, `em` and `%` are pretty much equivalent:
`100%` == `1em`
`50%` == `0.5em`

When designing grids, I would straight up think in percentages (or columns) rather than do that conversion by hand.

Comment: In those examples when he refers to "container" (context)... Is he saying that it is just that elements default size set by the browser?

Comment: `16px` is *usually* the default `font-size` set by the browser. A couple articles about `em` and its use in layouts: http://alistapart.com/article/elastic/ — http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201101/only_use_ems_for_the_total_width_of_em-based_layouts/

Answer (score 0):

There is good summary information about css measure units (especially about px and em) on this page https://pxtoem.net/learn

Also this service provides a converter between different css units so you can try them right away.

> EM Unit (em)
>
> An em is equal to the computed font-size of that
>   element’s parent. For example, If there is a div element defined with
>   font-size: 16px then for that div and for its children 1em = 16px. If
>   font-size is not defined explicitly, that element will inherit it from
>   the parent element. The inheritance continues to take place this way
>   amongst ancestors up until the root element. Default font-size of the
>   root element is provided by browser.
>
> Here is an example which will help you to understand how to use em
>   units:
>
> css:
>
> ```
> html {
>   font-size: 16px;
> }
>
> div {
>   font-size: 18px;
> }
>
> p {
>   font-size: 1.5em;
> }
>
> code {
>   font-size: 1.2em;
> }
> ```
>
> html:
>
> ```
> <html>
>   <body>
>
>     <div>
>       <p>
>         Font size here will be 27px (18 * 1.5)
>       </p>
>     </div>
>
>     <p>
>       Font size here will be 24px (16 * 1.5)
>     </p>
>
>     <code>
>       Font size here will be 19.2px (16 * 1.2)
>     </code>
>
>   </body>
> </html>
> ```

There is also similar code snippet on that page which demonstrates rem (root em) values which are relative to the root element size.

Answer (score 0):

In general the current answers seems right. There is an exception when styling tables using `<table>` and `table-layout; fixed`.

## Table columns

If you know roughly the number of characters a column needs to fit `em` generally underestimates the width. It is better and more accurate to go with the lesser know and used `ex` measure in this scenario. If you know the maximimum number of characters that go in a column set its `min-width` to that amount in `ex`.

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
table td:nth-child(1) {
  min-width: 10ex;
}
table td:nth-child(2) {
  min-width: 30ex;
}
```

Will set roughly 10 characters of space for the first and 30 for the second column.